# Get relational data based off logged in user

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, supabase

I have 3 tables in my supabase db: **users**, **teams** and **members**.

The **users table** contain all users that signed up with auth and gets added to the table with these details:

| id | displayname | email |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 602eff1e-6300-491e-b821-44eddb5f37cf | tester | test@test.com |

The **teams table** contains the teams that are created from the app with these details:

| id | team_name |
| --- | --- |
| 777a37bf-19cf-49c3-9b0a-911165ef0a2b | Test Team |

I've setup the **members table** with as such to make it a many to many relational middle ground once the signed in user creates a team their user id gets added here with the team id:

| id | user_id | team_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 602eff1e-6300-491e-b821-44eddb5f37cf | 777a37bf-19cf-49c3-9b0a-911165ef0a2b |

I'd like to query all the teams the current logged in user belongs to. I'm not 100% sure how to do this I was looking at the documentation on joining foreign tables but telling to be specific to the userid is throwing me off. I also feel like I'm making unnecessary functions to first get the team ids then based on the id get the names. An example:

```
  let getUserData = async () => {
    const { data, error } = await supabase
      .from("members")
      .select("team_id")
      .eq("user_id", user?.id);
    setProfileData(data);
  };

  let getTeamName = async () => {
    let { data, error } = await supabase
      .from("teams")
      .select("team_name")
      .eq(user.id);
    setTeamNames(data);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getUserData();
    getTeamName();
  }, []);
```

Comment: From a very brief impression: looks like supabase is not ideal for complex queries, seems that it expects you to create tables and views from which you can use a simple SELECT with some filtering. If you insist on using supabase you can create a view that joins the tables `members` and `teams` on `team_id` and then you'll be able to easily query such a view.

Comment: Thanks @nirAlfasi for the response. I'll try that approach. I'm not set in stone with Supabase. I thought it might be a nice db to use for this project but if I'll have an easier time with something basic like just normal SQL  then its prob better. I always just wonder/worry about query performance that might affect the app in the long run..

Answer (score 0):

https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/select#query-foreign-tables-through-a-join-table

Query foreign tables through a join table:

If you're in a situation where your tables are NOT directly related, but instead are joined by a join table, you can still use the select() method to query the related data. The join table needs to have the foreign keys as part of its composite primary key.

```sql
create table
  users (
    id int8 primary key,
    name text
  );
create table
  teams (
    id int8 primary key,
    name text
  );
-- join table
create table
  users_teams (
    user_id int8 not null references users,
    team_id int8 not null references teams,
    -- both foreign keys must be part of a composite primary key
    primary key (user_id, team_id)
  );

insert into
  users (id, name)
values
  (1, 'Kiran'),
  (2, 'Evan');
insert into
  teams (id, name)
values
  (1, 'Green'),
  (2, 'Blue');
insert into
  users_teams (user_id, team_id)
values
  (1, 1),
  (1, 2),
  (2, 2);
```

You can then query via supabase JS like so:

```js
const { data, error } = await supabase
  .from('users')
  .select(`
    name,
    teams (
      name
    )
  `)
```